# Why does eWAY Payment Gateway Lineitems show $0.00 price in the invoice section?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I have integrated eWAY payment gateway. The payments are handled successfully. The problem is that I can not display prices for lineitems correctly in the invoice section of the payment page. Currently all of them appear as $0.00.

[image: Screenshot]

This is what I coded to achieve above. I'm just setting lineitems via a loop:

```
if (!empty($summary_data)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($summary_data); $i++) {
                $customizations = implode(', ',array_merge($summary_data[$i]['additions'], $summary_data[$i]['minuses'], $summary_data[$i]['extra_info']));
                $customizations = !(empty($customizations))?" [".$customizations. "] ":$customizations;
                $desc = $summary_data[$i]['name'].$customizations;
                $item = new eWAY\LineItem();
                $item->SKU = "SKU" . $i;
                $item->Description = $desc;
                $item->Quantity = 1;
                $item->UnitCost = $summary_data[$i]['price'];
                $item->Tax = 0;
                $item->Total = $summary_data[$i]['price'];
                $request->Items->LineItem[$i] = $item;
            }
        }
```

Can you please point out what have I missed?

Comment: What is the value in `$summary_data[$i]['price']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can occur when passing through an invalid value. Please ensure you are passing through the amount in cents value. E.g. to pass $100, pass "10000"

If you require further assistance you can contact the local eWAY team 24/7 via phone or via our LiveChat on our websites.